# Can you recommend a package in R that can be used to count precision, recall and F1-score for multi class classification tasks

Tags: r, text-classification, precision-recall

Is there any package that you would recommend which can be used to calculate the precision, F1, recall for multi class classification task in R. I tried to use ROCR but it states that:

```
ROCR currently supports only evaluation of binary classification tasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you were looking for a solution in R. That said, this is a link to a nice solution  library in [Python, using scikit-learn version 0.14](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html). Python is very similar to R in a lot of respects (if you haven't used it before), and this could be a good place to start.

Another place you might want to look, if you are focused on R, is the the [PerfMeas](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerfMeas/PerfMeas.pdf) package. As I quote, this "Package implements different performance measures for
classiﬁcation and ranking tasks. AUC, precision at a given recall, F-score for single and multiple classes are available."

Comment: `caret` [on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) is a popular package for model building and evaluation, and it includes metrics you're looking for.